# upsert throws error when I pass Id as externalIdFieldName in Beatbox API while contacting Salesforce

Tags: python, api, salesforce

I'm using beatbox API to update/insert data in to salesforce opportunity object.

upsert() throws INVALID FIELD error when I pass Id as externalIDFieldName. Currently I'm using another unique external Id and it's working fine but I want to use the salesforce Id.

Please shed some light on what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already know the salesforce Id of the record, just call update instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify "Id" as an external key.

[see REST upsert documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_sobject_upsert.htm)

If you need to upsert based on Id, use SOAP API.